# do not follow mouse focus

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, window-manager

On my Ubuntu 14.04 I have a lightweight window manager `wmii` where a mouse motion changes a window's focus. This is annoying and I want to change this behaviour, i.e. if only I left-click on a window, the focus has to be switched to it. I'm not sure if this is a feature of X Window in general or this particular WM. How can I change the behaviour?

Comment: This is a feature of wmii called "sloppy focus", and from what I've seen it didn't seem to be configurable.